# Do I need to COM enable and register my Library?

Tags: .net, com, windows-installer, c#-2.0

I have a C# COM Enabled Library which talks to a third-party application.  I am using a Visual Studio Setup Project to register and populate a required registry key.

Should I be COM registering the Library.dll and/or Library.tlb file?

Note:
This question was based on the fact I was actually registering both files.  The actual problem was that the third-party program could not find either file based on its error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional research the reason my file could not be found was for an entirely different reason. The code to determine the value within a registry key was using the wrong value.

Answer (score 2):

If the Library.dll you mention **is using** the 3rd party application: No. You only need to set you .NET library to be COM visible and COM register it if it will be/might be used via the COM interface by other applications and libraries. Otherwise there is no point.

If the Library.dll you mention **is being used** the 3rd party application: Then yes, you need to COM register the DLL to make it visible to COM applications.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you only register the .tlb file.

That's at least enough to make it work with MS Access (that's what we are using COM Interop for).